# Heroku Build Fails on @import for SCSS

Tags: reactjs, heroku, sass, webpack-4

I have a react/webpack-4 app and am trying to build it on Heroku. When I build it on my machine it works completely fine, but on Heroku it spits out these errors:

```
ERROR in ./src/styles/main.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass loader/lib/loader.js): 

@import 'components/dashboard';
^

File to import not found or unreadable: components/dashboard.
```

It doesn't always break on the same @import statement in my main.scss file, but it always breaks on one of them.

This is my main.scss:

```
@import 'components/add-poster';
@import 'components/auth';
@import 'components/dashboard';
@import 'components/navigation';
```

All of the names match my files and are prefixed properly with an _ (ie: _dashboard.scss).

This is my prod webpack build file:

```
module.exports = merge(base, {
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        use: [ MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ], 
        test: /\.scss$/ 
      }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({ parallel: true, sourceMap: true }),
      new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({})
    ]
  },
  plugins: [ 
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'style.css'
    })
  ]
})
```

This has been driving me nuts for hours and any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After a very long and arduous process of reformatting webpack over and over again, I started removing imports to see if I could stop the error.

Once I removed the dashboard component the build started to work. I believe that my issue was actually from importing an scss file with nothing in it. Don't know why that would break things, but there you go.